# What and all attributes can I pass for paste_retain_style_properties property in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I can pass "all" as below.
paste_retain_style_properties:"all".

Need to know what and all can be passed to this separately.

Please see to the content copied v/s content pasted screenshots

[Content Copied,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaKl4.png)

[Content pasted in TinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrCD2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_retain_style_properties

> This option can be set to a space-separated list of CSS style names,
>   or "all" if you want all styles to be retained.

So effectively you can pass any CSS style name you like.

Comment: Here when I give all, it is not retaining the bullet points correctly (when I copied and pasted from Word). Do you have any solution for it ?

Comment: When you say "not retaining the bullet point" what do you mean?  You really need to update your question with **specific details** around the issue so someone can provide you assistance.

Comment: A screenshot of Word and TinyMCE don't tell anyone what content ends up in TinyMCE.  What HTML is in the editor?  That got there as a result of a paste I assume?  If so the `paste` plugin is responsible for processing the HTML that Word places in the clipboard.  Is the HTML reasonable based on what Word places in the clipboard?

Comment: May be I need to change the question to "how can I paste contents from word to tinymce incorporating all the styles?".